# Increase the imaginary part of complex number by a constant in matlab

Tags: matlab

I think this is a simple question, but I could not find an answer by googling.

Let's say that I have a code like this:

```
y1=1:0.01:2;
```

This creates 1x101 long cell, with numbers 1, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, etc.
Now I want to have an array of numbers which goes like 1, 1+0.01i, 1+0.02i, 1+0.03i, 1+0.04i, 1+0.05i, 1+0.06i, 1+0.07i, 1+0.08i, etc. I thought that the code `1:0.01i:2;` will give the answer, but I am getting a warning

> Warning: Colon operands must be real scalars.

How to get around this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should think about what does it mean to increase a complex number by `.01i`. Forget about Matlab. What would it mean mathematically?

Comment: I don't see why `y=0:.01:1;` and `z=1+i*y` shouldn't work. It gives exactly the sequence you want

Comment: @jrook , what is the problem in having that scenario? Why can't one have, for instance 1+1i, 1+2i, 1+3i, 1+4i, 1+5i, 1+6i, etc. This represents a straight line parallel to imaginary axis.
The second suggestion was one which I have not thought of it... Thanks for that.

Comment: `:` in Matlab is meant to be used in one dimension. It simply does not support what you have in mind. We have to conform to the language's rules, there is no escape from it!

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer. Please accept if it solves the problem. Cheers!

Comment: @jrook ,I accepted the answer. So the question and it's premises were not that bad, right?  :)

Comment: No the question was not a bad question. Stackoverflow suggests going through [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking questions. Personally, I have found that many of my questions were resolved halfway through that process. Cheers!

Comment: hm... still somebody has down-voted it... Anyway, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning message is trying to tell you, the `:` is meant to be used in only one dimension. It cannot keep the real part constant and only increase the imaginary part. Instead, do this:

```
y=0:.01:1;
z=1+i*y
```

and `z` will contain the values you want. Here is the relevant [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).